# Assembly static code with changing the variables

Tags: pointers, assembly

OK, so I wrote some code: the code needs to print 10 without changing actually the code, just the variables, I wrote it this way but it doesn't work for me, any help?  **Edit: it has to be with two variables!**

```
 //this two lines should be change
    num1_ptr dw 10 
    num1_ptr_ptr dw offset num1_ptr

    //no touch this four lines!      
            mov bx,num1_ptr_ptr
            mov bx,[bx]
            mov ax,[bx]
            call print_function
```

Comment: Why does `num1_ptr` have `ptr` in its name when it isn't a pointer? Judging by the code you would need 3 variables; `num1`, `num1_ptr`, and `num1_ptr_ptr`.

Comment: Is this MASM? Then I would be afraid that already first `mov bx,num1_ptr_ptr` is compiled as `mov bx,[num1_ptr_ptr]`, so then you would need 3 variables like Michael wrote. In normal Intel-syntax assembler (where first mov would load bx with offset num1_ptr_ptr value, not referencing memory) your code looks ok.

Comment: It's must to be with two lines,and two variables. I'll change their names

Comment: @Michael look my answer above

Comment: @Ped7g look my answer above

Comment: So what assembler you use (or even check it in debugger or with objdump, how those instructions are assembled)? And what means "it doesn't work for me"? I can take your solution, adjust syntax a bit to be NASM compilable, and it will work (calling print_function with value 10 in ax). If the first `mov` is dereferencing memory already, I don't see any simple way to do it with two variables (you would have to find `word 10` value somewhere in memory and fill the first variable with address of it, which doesn't sound like the proper solution, unless you are at some hacking/RE class).

Comment: Also how is "print_function" defined? Maybe it takes two ascii chars in ax, so 0x3031 or 0x3130 would then be correct value? It's not completely clear, what you are trying to achieve, and what you have at disposal (that source has different meaning in different assemblers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is MASM (`mov bx,num1_ptr_ptr` does fetch the value, not address), and you "can change these two lines", then maybe this "hack" would do (introducing third value by defining two words at first line):

```
    num1_ptr       dw    10, offset num1_ptr
    num1_ptr_ptr   dw    offset num1_ptr+2
```

Comment: @DRJ ok, but this is sort of cheating, using 3 word variables... Then again it doesn't look like there is other way around, I hope at least you understand what I did, and why "+2" (calculating address beyond the `word 10` value).